# .Net Core Version Confusion on Installer

Tags: .net-core

[image]

Is this confusing to anyone else?

What's the story?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agree, that text in button is a little bit confusing, as it actually means the following:

> Download .NET Core SDK for [.NET Core 1.1.1](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/1.1/1.1.1.md)

And as .NET Core SDK version is [1.0.1](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/sdk), you see that message in the intallation window's title.