# .NET Core Version Numbers

Tags: .net-core

I have .NET Core installed and I am a little confused about the version numbers I am seeing. When I run the `dotnet` command, I get this output:

```
Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 1.1.0
  Build    : 928f77c4bc3f49d892459992fb6e1d5542cb5e86

Usage: dotnet [common-options] [[options] path-to-application]

Common Options:
  --help                           Display .NET Core Shared Framework Host help.
  --version                        Display .NET Core Shared Framework Host version.

Options:
  --fx-version            Version of the installed Shared Framework to use to run the application.
  --additionalprobingpath    Path containing probing policy and assemblies to probe for.

Path to Application:
  The path to a .NET Core managed application, dll or exe file to execute.

If you are debugging the Shared Framework Host, set 'COREHOST_TRACE' to '1' in your environment.

To get started on developing applications for .NET Core, install the SDK from:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
```

That is telling me I have .NET Core v1.1.0, which is what I expected based on what I installed.

However, if I then run `dotnet --version`, it tells me I have version `1.0.1`. Why the discrepancy? What is the difference between these two version numbers?

Comment: I wrote http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net-core/9592/components-and-versioning-in-net-core#t=201704252158540031514 a few weeks ago. Hope it helps.

Comment: That note is trying to explain 1. versions are different between teh components and 2. how to find each version. Trying to keep a track of latest versions is kind of too much manual work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 1.0.1 is a .NET Core SDK version
- 1.1.1 is a .NET Core runtime version

See related SO question [.Net Core Version Confusion on Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42738072/2833802)

Comment: To be very pedantic, 1.1.1 is the version of the shared host, not the shared framework. Basically the version of https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup, not the version of https://github.com/dotnet/corefx or https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr.